# Logstash mail events from logstash-forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

My task is to send email notifications if cron writes an error in /var/log/cron.log.

My logstash-forwarder.conf:

```
{
    "network": {
        "servers": [ "myserver.domain.com:5000" ],
        "timeout": 15,
        "ssl key": "/etc/logstash/logstash.key",
        "ssl certificate": "/etc/logstash/logstash.crt",
        "ssl ca": "/etc/logstash/ca.crt"
    },

    "files": [
{
        "paths": [
        "/var/log/syslog"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
},
{
    "paths": [
        "/var/log/cron.log"
    ],
    "fields": { "type": "cron" }
}
    ]
}
```

logstash-input.conf:

```
input {
    lumberjack {
        port => 5000
        type => "logs"
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/private/logstash.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/private/logstash.key"
    }
}
```

logstash-filter.log:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
    }
}
filter {
    if [message] == "CRON" and [message] == "error" {
    throttle {
    key => "%{message}"
    add_tag => "catched"
        }
    }
}
```

logstash-output.conf:

```
output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    if "catched" in [tags] {
        email {
            from => "logstash@someserver.com"
            to => "user@someserver.com"
            subject => "Alert from  %{path}, from %{host}"
            body => "Message is: \n'%{message}'. \nLog file:\n %{path}:\n\n%{message}.\n More information can be viewed in Kibana"
        }
    }
}
```

Now all events are mailed to me. How can i get only error events from cron.log? Are they filtered by add_tag section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a content of  your `/var/log/cron.log`. 
I think you have conditional  issue.  Try use this:

```
if [type] == "cron" and [message] =~ /error/ {
    throttle {
    key => "%{message}"
    add_tag => "catched"
        }
    }
```